# How to measure performance of a managed thread in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, performance, clr

I want to measure performance of a managed (.NET) thread. To be specific, I need to measure following -

1. How long the thread is using CPU?
2. How long it remained blocked (waiting for completion of a remote method call)?

Using System.Diagnostic.StopWatch is not helpful, becuase it reads high resolution performance timers feature of OS/Hardware which may include time consumed by other threads running parallely and sharing the same CPU.

Answer (score 4):

You can use approach described here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ExecutionStopwatch.aspx
which uses system function GetThreadTimes 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237(v=vs.85).aspx

Waiting time is the difference between total time and execution time.

Added:
I like to use disposable class to measure performance - it keeps code clean (hardcoded console usage just for example):

```
public class ThreadPerformance : IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch _totalStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private ExecutionStopwatch _executionStopwatch = new ExecutionStopwatch();

    public static ThreadPerformance Measure()
    {
        return new ThreadPerformance();
    }

    private ThreadPerformance()
    {
        _totalStopwatch.Start();
        _executionStopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _executionStopwatch.Stop();
        _totalStopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Performance mesurement for thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting: {0}", _totalStopwatch.Elapsed - _executionStopwatch.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("CPU usage: {0}", _executionStopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Usage is very simple:

```
static void ThreadProc()
{
    using (ThreadPerformance.Measure())
    {
        // do some calculations and waitings here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lazyberezovsky. I was thinking on same line. I am not sure whether this solution will work without any problem on different OS platforms/.NET versions/hardware platforms. Microsoft documentation does not give any assurance that the .NET managed thread will always get mapped to the same unmanaged thread. What if the GetCurrentThread() returns different thread handles in two separate calls?

Comment: @Nitin You could use `System.Threading.Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()` and `Thread.EndThreadAffinity()` to lock the current managed thread to a specific unmanaged thread. However, I suspect that this could change the threading behaviour/performance of the code being timed, because the CLR host would have less freedom to schedule its managed threads. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity) mention  SQL Server hosted .NET code as a scenario where threads are moved around.

Comment: Upon further reflection, using `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()` does not solve the problem completely: there is nothing to stop the CLR host scheduling **other** managed threads to the same unmanaged thread that is being timed, which would misleadingly increase the measured execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Managed Stack Explorer](http://mse.codeplex.com/) help.